# Implementing EntityManager Compile errors

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, java-ee-7

I'm working on creating an AuditableEntityManager that puts a json message into a JMS queue routed to an ELK cluster for audit purposes.

Most of the implementations is just pass through, so for instance I have

```
EntityManager entityManager_ = null;

public AuditableEntityManagerImpl(String name, 
                                PersistenceProperty [] properties, 
                                SynchronizationType synchronization,
                                PersistenceContextType type,
                                String unitName)
{
  //TODO - Figure out how to configure the rest of the properties
  entityManager_ = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(name).createEntityManager();
}
```

And most methods look like

```
@Override
public <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object primaryKey)
{
  return entityManager_.find(entityClass, primaryKey);
}
```

With the exception of the mutable methods which have todo blocks where I'll put the auditing parser

```
@Override
public void remove(Object entity)
{
  entityManager_.remove(entity);
  //TODO - LOG to audit
}
```

I allowed eclipse to populate the missing methods from the interface and in the IDE all is green.  When I try to build though (using maven) I get a pile of errors stating that much of the javax.peristence stuff can't be found and that many of the methods don't exist in EntityManager.  I've flushed my .m2/repository to make sure it wasn't something corrupt in there, but no luck.

The error stack is below, apologies for the length.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[6,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGraph
  location: package javax.persistence
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[16,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StoredProcedureQuery
  location: package javax.persistence
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[17,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SynchronizationType
  location: package javax.persistence
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[20,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CriteriaDelete
  location: package javax.persistence.criteria
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[22,34] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CriteriaUpdate
  location: package javax.persistence.criteria
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[31,37] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SynchronizationType
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[194,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CriteriaUpdate
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[200,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CriteriaDelete
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[242,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StoredProcedureQuery
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[248,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StoredProcedureQuery
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[254,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StoredProcedureQuery
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[260,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class StoredProcedureQuery
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[326,14] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGraph
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[332,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGraph
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[338,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGraph
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[344,19] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class EntityGraph
  location: class psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManager.java:[14,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SynchronizationType
  location: package javax.persistence
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManager.java:[24,3] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class SynchronizationType
  location: @interface psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManager.java:[24,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SynchronizationType
  location: @interface psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[200,16] createQuery(CriteriaDelete) in psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl cannot implement <T>createQuery(javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T>) in javax.persistence.EntityManager
  return type javax.persistence.Query is not compatible with javax.persistence.TypedQuery<T>
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[182,16] name clash: createQuery(java.lang.String) in psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl overrides a method whose erasure is the same as another method, yet neither overrides the other
  first method:  <T>createQuery(javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery<T>) in psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
  second method: createQuery(CriteriaDelete) in psu.edu.javaee.audit.producer.AuditableEntityManagerImpl
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[241,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[244,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(java.lang.String)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[247,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[250,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createStoredProcedureQuery(java.lang.String)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[253,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[256,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createStoredProcedureQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.Class[])
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[259,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[262,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createStoredProcedureQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[271,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[274,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isJoinedToTransaction()
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[325,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[328,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createEntityGraph(java.lang.Class<T>)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[331,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[334,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method createEntityGraph(java.lang.String)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[337,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[340,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getEntityGraph(java.lang.String)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[343,3] method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[ERROR] /home/shawn/git/auditable-entity-manager/auditable-entity-manager-common/src/main/java/psu/edu/javaee/audit/producer/AuditableEntityManagerImpl.java:[346,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getEntityGraphs(java.lang.Class<T>)
  location: variable entityManager_ of type javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

Comment: Eclipse is using JPA 2.1 annotations, while your maven build is likely using JPA 1.0 jars that don't have the new classes

Comment: You're absolutely  right Chris, thanks.  Unfortunately my toolset was giving me bad information too.

Answer (score 0):

Bad archetype = bad pom + eclipse showing a javaee-api version 1.7, but 1.6 is on the classpath.  Cleaning the pom up sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I was trying to use `entityManager.getEntityGraph("mygraph")`, but Eclipse was giving me the error, "The method getEntityGraph is undefined for type EntityManager".

To solve it, I removed a dependency from my pom.xml.  I had both of the following and I deleted the bottom one.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```